# Locations of crafting stations

Tags: battle-chasers-nightwar

Throughout the various explorable locations, there are specific crafting stations that allow your heroes to craft items.  I'm looking for a list of locations that allow you to craft without wandering around the various (randomized?) dungeons.

Harms's Way only seems to have a potion crafting station in the Curio Shoppe.  I'm just past the Junktown quest, so I'm not sure if the city unlocks additional crafting stations as the game progresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you progress through the game, you can upgrade your merchants/vendors to allow you to use their crafting station, but it'll cost you several thousand gold per merchant. There's even a tip about it in the loading screens and game manual in the escape menu.

Alternatively, you can go to the lowest level dungeon and go there on the lowest difficulty to easily breeze through the rooms and find a randomly placed crafting station.

Comment: Yah it appears that you can upgrade some shops to get crafting stations in town.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the enchanting station, although I'm pretty much at the end stages of the game. Doesn't seem like it can be paid for to be in the town.

Comment: I knocked down the sign at the beginning of the game ... I'm wondering if that has anything to do with the enchanting station?

Comment: Now you made me wonder too :) I hope it was just for that "hey do you know who knocked down my sign?" line.  Guess you could ask that in a separate question